# "personally" indicates that someone did the job himself, while not necessarily did that on his own, is my understanding right?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/NHTJPd7cnBU?t=200) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> Wienert revealed that during one episode he **personally** assembled a Polynesian-style bamboo
>   raft off-camera only for Grylls to add the finishing touches and take the credit.

[cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/personally) gives this explanation about personally

> If you do something personally, you do it yourself rather than asking someone else to do it

So, "personally" indicates that Wienert did the job himself, while not necessarily did that on his own. "personally" is being used here justify Wienert went through the whole procedure. is my understanding right?

Comment: I would understand from that sentence that he did it on his own.

Comment: @KateBunting So, "personally" could be used to indicate "on his own" in some situations, such as this case, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the [Cambs Dict. definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/personally) you linked to here.

> **done by you and not by someone else:**
>   *These figures should be correct because I've checked them personally.*

Using *personally* in these kinds of sentences indicates a direct involvement in the action.

> ***he*** personally **assembled**

To me, this means that he assembled it himself. Note the '*he*', indicating he was the sole party.

But this could be more than one person if specified:

> ***The crew and I*** personally assembled

This would mean he assembled it with the crew - but he would need to include them in the list of people who *personally* did the activity.

It all depends on the actors specified, and the activity

> ***he*** personally **oversaw** the assembly

In this instance, *he* had a sole supervisory role, but didn't necessarily get involved in the actual assembly itself. (He just told the crew how to build it)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful. Which item/explanation/definition of Cambs you are using?

Comment: @peterpanai The one you linked to in OP and the one I've linked in the first line of my answer